# import css file with media queries inside

Tags: css, media-queries

I would like to know If I can import css file that have a media queries inside into another css file.

And how?

> @import url("style.css") (min-width: 940px);

I've tried this. But I don't want to import a style like a media queries. I want to import style that have inside media queries.

thanks

Comment: If you are looking at importing stylesheets, you should use a pre-processor such as SASS. I'd advice you to look in to that. That way you still generate a single stylesheet which has a lighter load, but you still keep an overview for yourself in seperate files.

Comment: Or, what are you trying to do that `@import` doesn't do?

Comment: thanks timo, I'm working now with LESS (I begin with LESS). Is posible todo this with LESS.

Comment: Thanks Mr lister but with @import I cannot to import a CSS file that have inside a media queries. Or I don´t konw

Comment: @user2978441 Not sure, not really that experienced with LESS. But judging from the documentation, it should work the same as importing on SASS. `You can import a .less file, and all the variables in it will be available. The extension is optionally specified for .less files.`

Answer (score 0):

You can import css using media queries like so:

```
@import url("style.css") (min-width: 940px);
```

It might be worth looking into SASS as well so you don't have to use lots of style sheets and can have one that only has what you need in it.

http://sass-lang.com/